# Where are the "busy" jobs in Sidekiq stored?

Tags: sidekiq

In Sidekiq Pro, when clicking on the "Busy" tab, there are jobs running for about 2 months or so. I can't seem to find them when doing:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new("medium")
queue.each do |job|
  job.klass # => 'MyWorker'
  job.args # => [1, 2, 3]
  job.delete if job.jid == 'abcdef1234567890'
end
```

It doesn't seem like this "busy" jobs are using resources or anything, but they just keep showing in the "Busy" tab. Where this is tab reading the information from?

Answer (score 3):

```
w = Sidekiq::Workers.new
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#workers

Semi-recent versions had a leak in this data.  See 4.1.2 and 4.1.3:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md#413

Comment: Thanks! This is almost what I need... but I'm getting hashes instead of Sidekiq Job objects or something I can call methods on. Is there any way to stop the jobs from here? I mean, the works are actually stored into Redis, right? How can I stop this "process_ids"? It's a Redis thing? Thank you again for your help

Comment: The "jobs" have long since died.  The data is leaked and won't go away.  Read the changelog for a script which will expire it.